# Named route is not defined in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

Instead of redirecting, I'm receiving the error below. Why?

> Route [moderator.products] not defined.

These are my routes in a middleware's group function:

```php
Route::get('moderator/products', [ModeratorController::class, 'products'])
    ->name('moderator.products');
Route::redirect('/', route('moderator.products'));
```

Comment: Try run this command in terminal  " php artisan route:cache " or " php artisan route:clear "

Comment: @PedroCosta Did not help. Get the same mistake in the terminal

Comment: Run this php artisan route:list and show me the result

Comment: Since this is all defined in a closure, it's likely the named route doesn't exist yet; try just using "/moderator/products" as the second parameter to `Route::redirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by naming the route first without chaining it at the end.

```php
Route::name('moderator.products')->get('moderator/products', [ModeratorController::class, 'products']);

Route::redirect('/', route('moderator.products'));
```

I tested them. It reidrects to the mentioned named route. All you need to do is to first call the `name()` then chain the `get()`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, and this did not solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I got around this by not using the named route, and using the url, i.e. swap `route('moderator.products')` for `url('moderator/products')`.

EDIT: I did a bunch of code editing to get past my problem, so I'm not sure, but I suspect my issue was caused by naming the exact same route twice. Double check to make sure you haven't done this if you get this problem.